# Set constant SERVER_NAME with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have **nginx.conf** with following structure:

```
http {
    [ ... ]

    server {
        [ ... ]

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $host;
            fastcgi_read_timeout  3000;
            include  fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

This nginx runs inside Docker so it has no idea, which domain is linked to it (there is nginx reverse proxy on hosting system). But I have a problem that when I try to acces `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` from PHP, it's empty... How can I set it to constant value? When I tried:

```
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME example.com
```

it's still empty.

Please note that I have to use `SERVER_NAME`, because it's in 3rd part code.

Comment: Sorry for obvious question, but do you reload nginx config?

Comment: Yes I tried, but without success...

Comment: It reloads without errors? Everything looks right, except string `fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME example.com` — no semicolon at the end.

Comment: Declare your `fastcgi_param` statements **after** the `include fastcgi_params;` statement. Only the last statement takes effect, so the `include` *may* overwrite your desired settings.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you! Feel free to post it as answer, I will accept it as solution.

Comment: Not directly related to your issue, but note that using `$host` will drop off any port number that might be present.  Because I was running inside Docker on a nonstandard port, I had to use `$http_host` instead to make sure the port number got included too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiple `fastcgi_param` statements (at the same block level) setting the same parameter will silently use the value from the last statement. *This includes statements read via an `include` directive*.

Always declare `fastcgi_param` statements after the `include fastcgi_params;` statement to avoid any ambiguity in your configuration files.