# How Can I override $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in nginx configuration

Tags: php, nginx, reverse-proxy

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /Users/name/cert/example.dev.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /Users/name/cert/example.dev-key.pem;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    server_name example.dev;

    location / {
     proxy_pass             http://localhost:8000;
     proxy_read_timeout     60;
     proxy_connect_timeout  60;
     proxy_redirect         off;
    }

}
```

I have been try with below options. But still getting only localhost on $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

- `proxy_set_header Host $host;`
- `include fastcgi_params; fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME proptexx.dev;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set constant SERVER\_NAME with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610794/set-constant-server-name-with-nginx)

Comment: hide any "nginx" information https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/hide-nginx-server-version-header/

Comment: Did you found a solution? Looking into the same issue.